# ListPointPlot3D: Blend is not a Graphics3D primitive or directive

Tags: plotting

I'm trying to color-code points in a ListPointPlot3D using

```
fun[x_, y_, z_] := -Log[x*y*z]
test = Table[{i, j, k}, {i, 0.1, 1, 0.1}, {j, 0.1, 1, 0.1}, {k, 0.1, 
     1, 0.1}] // Flatten[#, 2] &;
ListPointPlot3D[test, 
 ColorFunction -> (ColorData["TemperatureMap"][fun[##]] &)]
```

, which seems to work alright except I get an error message: `Blend is not a Graphics3D primitive or directive.` and the plot is shaded red.
[image]

Curiously enough, if I remove the `Log` in the function, or turn `ColorFunctionScaling->False`, it works as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the option `ColorFunctionScaling -> False` to prevent the arguments supplied to the color function from being scaled to lie between 0 and 1 (this scaling is the default behavior). When the arguments are scaled, for `{x, y, z} = {0, 0, 0}` we get

```
ColorData["TemperatureMap"][fun[0, 0, 0]]
```

> Blend["TemperatureMap", ∞]

which triggers the error message.

Adding the option `ColorFunctionScaling -> False`:

```
ListPointPlot3D[test, 
 ColorFunction -> (ColorData["TemperatureMap"][fun[##]] &), 
 ColorFunctionScaling -> False]
```

[image]

Comment: Oh, I see. I thought it might be a problem in the dataset I made, but the problem lies in the scaling function itself.